# How to create a custom Node class?

Tags: java, javafx, custom-controls

I am new to java and javafx. I tried to creaate a custom class to show timepicker, but it don't render the node visually.

What's wrong with the following class?

```
package customcombobox;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class TLTimePicker extends GridPane{
private int hr = 1;
private int min;
private int sec;
private String meas = "AM";
private String value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;    
private final VBox timePicker = new VBox(5);       

public TLTimePicker(){
    this.render();
}

public TLTimePicker(int hour, int minute, int second, String measure){
    this.hr = hour;
    this.min = minute;
    this.sec = second;
    this.meas = measure;
    this.value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;  
    this.render();
}

public GridPane render(){
    HBox contnr = new HBox();
    TextField txtfld = new TextField();
    txtfld.setEditable(false);
    Button open = new Button();
    contnr.getChildren().addAll(txtfld, open);
    ImageView arrow = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("down.png")));
    open.setGraphic(arrow);        
    arrow.setFitWidth(12);
    arrow.setFitHeight(12);
    Label hrLbl = new Label("Hour");
    Spinner hour = new Spinner(1, 13, 1);
    Label mntLbl = new Label("minute");
    Spinner minute = new Spinner(0, 61, 0);
    Label scnLbl = new Label("second");
    Spinner second = new Spinner(0, 61, 0);
    ComboBox<String> ampm = new ComboBox<String>();
    ampm.getItems().addAll("AM", "PM");
    ampm.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    hour.setPrefWidth(52);
    minute.setPrefWidth(52);
    second.setPrefWidth(52);
    ampm.setPrefWidth(64);
    hour.setEditable(true);
    minute.setEditable(true);
    second.setEditable(true);    

    txtfld.setText(value);

    hour.valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
        hr = (int)nv;
        if(ov.equals(12)) {
            hour.getValueFactory().setValue(1);
            hr = 1;
        }          
        String value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;
        txtfld.setText(value);
    });

    minute.valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
        min = (int)nv;
        if(ov.equals(60)) {
            minute.getValueFactory().setValue(0);
            min = 0;
        }

        String value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;
        txtfld.setText(value);
    });

    second.valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
        sec = (int)nv;
        if(ov.equals(60)) {
            second.getValueFactory().setValue(0);
            sec = 0;
        }
        String value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;
        txtfld.setText(value);
    });        

    ampm.setOnAction((event) -> {
        meas = ampm.getValue();
        String value = hr+":"+ min +":"+ sec +" "+meas;
        txtfld.setText(value);
    });       

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.add(hrLbl, 0, 0);
    grid.add(hour, 1, 0);
    grid.add(mntLbl, 0, 1);
    grid.add(minute, 1, 1);
    grid.add(scnLbl, 0, 2);
    grid.add(second, 1, 2);
    grid.setHgap(5);
    grid.setVgap(5);        

    timePicker.getChildren().addAll(grid, ampm);
    timePicker.setStyle("-fx-background-color:"
            + "#ededed; -fx-border-color: "
            + "#dddddd; -fx-border-size:1;"
            + "-fx-padding:5 25;");
    hidetimePicker();        
    arrow.setRotate(0);

    EventHandler showHide = (event) -> {
        Object[] obj = {hour, minute, second};
        String[] arr = txtfld.getText().split("[\\s:]+");
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++ ){
            if(arr[i].matches("^(\\d+)$")) {
                ((Spinner)obj[i]).getValueFactory().setValue(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
            } else {
                ampm.setValue(arr[i].toUpperCase());
            }
        }       
        if(timePicker.visibleProperty().getValue()) {
            hidetimePicker();
            arrow.setRotate(0);
        } else {
            timePicker.setVisible(true);
            timePicker.setManaged(true);
            arrow.setRotate(180);
        }
    };

    open.setOnAction(showHide);        
    txtfld.setOnMousePressed(showHide);

    GridPane group = new GridPane();
    group.add(contnr, 0, 0);
    group.add(timePicker, 0, 1);
    timePicker.toFront();

    Scene scene = group.getScene();
//        scene.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
//            hidetimePicker();
//            arrow.setRotate(0);
//        }); 



    return group;
}  

private void hidetimePicker(){
    timePicker.setVisible(false);
    timePicker.setManaged(false);        
}    

}
```

**Call it**
It show a blank window after being called with this.

```
package customcombobox;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class demo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        TLTimePicker timer = new TLTimePicker(5,27,0,"PM");
        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.getChildren().add(timer);
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 350, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TimePicker");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should use fxml files for a layout hierarchy of this depth.
Then I noticed, you return a GridPane from the render method but you just call it in the constructor while you don&#39;t use its value... Is that possible?
So your GridPane group at the end is obsolete since you can just add the content to "this", because your class already is a(n empty) GridPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `render()` a little bit.
First, make the method `void`:

```
public void render() {
    // most part of your code just stays as it is
    ...
```

then second, change the last lines (commented out are your lines, the rest makes it work):

```
    ...
    // GridPane group = new GridPane(); ---> you don't need a new one
    // group.add(contnr, 0, 0);
    // group.add(timePicker, 0, 1);
    this.add(contnr, 0, 0);
    this.add(timePicker, 0, 1);
    timePicker.toFront();

    // Scene scene = group.getScene();
    // scene.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
    // hidetimePicker();
    // arrow.setRotate(0);
    // });

    // return group;
}
```

You could also call `GridPane timer = new TLTimePicker(5,27,0,"PM").render()` in your `demo` instead of `TLTimePicker timer = new TLTimePicker(5,27,0,"PM")` and not change anything else to make it work, which would make extending GridPane somehow obsolete…